# App folder in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp framework. I used composer to install cakephp. But when I want to try the blog tutorial, I find the app folder is missing from the composer installation. Is it a directory I've to create manually? Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do it. Rather you can download cakephp skeleton from here:
https://github.com/cakephp/app

Comment: still I'm unable to find the app folder.

Comment: According to their instructions http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html there are app,lib,vendors folder. But these are missing from composer installation.

Comment: Which version of cakephp you are trying to install?

Comment: You must be trying to install cakephp 3.*

Comment: You are right. I am trying to install cakephp3.*

Comment: ok what I need now is to follow 3.x documentation. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As described in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html you should :
 composer self-update && composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name 
 The needed folders should automatically be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the cakephp repository from github

```
 git clone -b 2.7 git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git
```

you can also follow the simple guide from here. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-cakephp-on-cloud/

You will find the app folder after installation.